# I want to check how long it takes to upload google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I am uploading data from DeskTop to google cloud storage using cloud sdk.

I'd like to check the time of upload.

Is there a way to check? 
(upload start time, upload endtime, total required time)

Does the DeskTop specification affect the upload time?

Comment: How are you uploading objects to Cloud Storage [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects ]? If you are using `gsutil cp [LOCAL_OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/` adding time before gsutil will give you the time of the operation. Like this: `time gsutil cp [LOCAL_OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/`

Comment: @GonçaloAlbino Thank you! May I ask you question? What does A, b, and c mean in time?

Comment: As you can see executing the command `time help` it means: "real time, user CPU time,and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates". Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @GonçaloAlbino Thank you very much for your kind answers! I was looking for it!

Comment: Great. Then I'm going to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [uploading objects to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) if you are using gsutil:

```
gsutil cp [LOCAL_OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/
```

you can add `time` before gsutil and the time of the operation will be returned. Like this:

```
time gsutil cp [LOCAL_OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/
```

Running the command `help time` shows you the meaning of real, user and sys:
"real time, user CPU time,and system CPU time spent executing PIPELINE when it terminates"